Building Spring Boot Docker image in GitHub Actions
This is my workflow:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew

      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/actions/setup-gradle@417ae3ccd767c252f5661f1ace9f835f9654f2b5 # v3.1.0

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build


      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build Docker
        run: docker build --platform linux/amd64 -f ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/live_server .

      - name: Push Docker
        run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/live_server:latest

Everything works well even up to Docker Login but when Build Docker runs I am getting error like this:
Run docker build --platform linux/amd64 -f ***
  docker build --platform linux/amd64 -f ***
  
  /live_server .
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/17.0.11-9/x64
    JAVA_HOME_17_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/17.0.11-9/x64
    GRADLE_BUILD_ACTION_SETUP_COMPLETED: true
    GRADLE_BUILD_ACTION_CACHE_RESTORED: true
  
ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.

My Dockerfile is in the right place it is in the root directory of the project and I cannot find where the error is coming from.

It seems like your username has line breaks in it.

well the username worked fine because the login succeded I think?? or is there something i am not considering?

i removed the username and it worked!! i do not know how but it did thank you so much

Are you using a personal token or password? They are different and behave differently when authenticating. Maybe it's because of that.

the token and passwords were correct i just had linebreaks on them
